# How to know what is the real graphic card on a RDP box

Tags: graphics-card

I'm remotely logged in to a Windows Server 2012. It shows Microsoft Basic Graphic Card when I use  WMIC path to query video controller. So does device manager show.

Is it possible to query real graphic card while connected through RDP? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Archer, It shows that you have to install the graphics driver because the microsoft basic graphic card is a basic driver for the windows servers or pc's to find your graphics card by running 'dxdiag' or if you can't find it there then use 'CPU-Z' this could be able to show the every hardware details.